# Fabric for AndroidStudio/Eclipse - Unable to Login with another user

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, logout, twitter-fabric

I have logged with my account in Fabric, but now I want to login with another account and I can't change user in Eclipse/Android Studio. There isn't any button to logout or something like that. Some help?? Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I am also facing the same issue. Fabric is a collection third part API which can be used to login to Twitter and post/display tweets. It also has APIs for monetization, crash report handling.

Got the answer

**1. Click on the 'Fabric' on Eclipse task bar so that the Fabric window is in focus.
2. Press Ctrl+L**

Comment: Did not work for me. can u please elaborate the steps. please.

Comment: @ManasRanjan try to restart your android studio, i was able to log out after

Answer (score 7):

You have to do 2 steps and your issue will resolved.

1. **For Android Studio Click on 'Fabric' icon / For Eclipse Click on the 'Fabric' on Eclipse task bar so that the Fabric window is in focus.**
2. **For Windows/linux User Press Ctrl+L and For MAC Press Control+L**
3. **And the last step is optional If your fabric is not logout. So, you need to restart your IDE.**

Answer (score 3):

Just hit Ctrl+L to log out! (when you focused on plugin)